# q-polynomials in terms of a basis

Tags: reference-request, co.combinatorics, linear-algebra, polynomials

Consider the polynomials
$$f_n(q)=\prod_{j=1}^n(1+q^j) \qquad \text{and} \qquad g_m(q)=1+q+q^2+\cdots+q^m.$$
I'll list a few examples to motivate my question. Direct calculations show that
$$f_1=g_1, \qquad f_2=g_3, \qquad f_3=g_6+q^3g_0, \qquad f_4=g_{10}+q^3g_4, 
\qquad f_5=g_{15}+q^3g_9+q^5g_5, \qquad etc.$$

I would then ask:

> **QUESTION 1.** Are there (numerical) coefficients $a_k\in\mathbb{Z}$ such that the following holds?
> $$f_n(q)=\sum_{k\geq0}a_k\cdot q^k\cdot g_{\binom{n+1}2-2k}(q).$$

> **QUESTION 2.** If so, are $a_k\geq0$?

**Postscript.** Richard Stanley responded with a confirmation to the above questions. If it is alright, I like to change them to the following:
**can you find the coefficients $a_k$ explicitly?**

**Remark.** If Question 2 is answered positively, then we get a new proof of $f_n$ being symmetric and unimodal.

Comment: Both questions have positive answers, an immediate consequence of the known fact that $f_n(q)$ has symmetric (palindromic) and unimodal coefficients.

Comment: Indeed, true. I was hoping for someone to answer without heavily bearing on the fact you mentioned (partly because it itself is proved using "nifty" methods). Also, if I'm not mistaken, $f_n$ do not have a combinatorial proof for symmetry+unimodality. So, I was thinking the above transformation would offer a chance at it. Perhaps, I will change the question slightly.

Comment: If $f_n(q)=\sum c_i q^i$ then $a_k=c_k-c_{k-1}$. I don't think there's much hope of finding $a_k$ (or $c_k$) explicitly.

Comment: I think if you were hoping for an answer of a particular kind, or avoiding a particular fact, you should have mentioned that in body of the question.

Answer (score 0):

I'm convinced that an "explicit" form for $a_k$ might be ambitious. So, here is a sketchy argument for $a_k\geq0$ by induction. One can easily find a base case.

Denote $\Delta_n=\binom{n+1}2$ and $\Delta^*_n=\lfloor\frac12\Delta_n\rfloor$. Suppose $f_n(q)=\sum_{k=0}^{\Delta^*_n}a_kq^kg_{\Delta_n-2k}(q)$ where each $a_k\geq0$. By definition, we know $f_{n+1}(q)=(1+q^{n+1})f_n(q)$ and hence
\begin{align}
f_{n+1}(q):&=\sum_{k=0}^{\Delta^*_n}a_kq^kg_{\Delta_n-2k}(q)
+\sum_{k=0}^{\Delta^*_n}a_kq^{n+1+k}g_{\Delta_n-2k}(q) \\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{\Delta^*_n}a_k(q^k+\cdots+{\color{red}{q^{\Delta_n-k}}})
+\sum_{k=0}^{\Delta^*_n}a_k(q^{n+1+k}+\cdots+{\color{blue}{q^{\Delta_{n+1}-k}}}) \\
&=\sum_{k_1=0}^{\Delta^*_n}a_{k_1}(q^{k_1}+\cdots+{\color{blue}{q^{\Delta_{n+1}-k_1}}})
+\sum_{k_2=0}^{\Delta^*_n}a_{k_2}(q^{n+1+k_2}+\cdots+{\color{red}{q^{\Delta_n-k_2}}}) \\
&=\sum_{k_1=0}^{\Delta^*_n}a_{k_1}q^{k_1}(1+\cdots+q^{\Delta_{n+1}-2k_1})
+\sum_{k_2=0}^{\Delta^*_n}a_{k_2}q^{n+1+k_2}(1+\cdots+q^{\Delta_{n+1}-2(n+1+k_2)}) \\
&=\sum_{k_1=0}^{\Delta^*_n}a_{k_1}q^kg_{\Delta_{n+1}-2k_1}(q)
+\sum_{k_2=0}^{\Delta^*_n}a_{k_2}q^{n+1+k_2}g_{\Delta_{n+1}-2(n+1+k_2)}(q).
\end{align}
Apart from rearrangement and collapsing like-terms, the coefficients can only be non-negative again.

Comment: I do not understand the third line in the formula. What happens to those $k$ from the second line which satisfy $\Delta_n-k<n+k$, so the two sums are separated?

Comment: @IlyaBogdanov, the second sum on line two is split with $(q^{n+1+k}+\cdots+q^{\Delta_{n+1}-k}) = (q^{n+1+k}+\cdots+q^{\Delta_n-k}) + (q^{\Delta_n-k+1}+\cdots+q^{\Delta_{n+1}-k})$, and then the second part is merged with the first sum.

Comment: @PeterTaylor  The first sum after the equality sign may consist of a +negative* number of terms...

Comment: As far as I know, there is no known short elementary proof of this unimodality (which is equivalent to non-negativity of $a_k$'s)...